# Unable to get simple passportjs with mongoose working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using [passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose) and trying to setup a simple working example using  the [login example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/login) in the repository. But I'm running into problems and I get an error message saying "Error: failed to serialize user into session".

I have reproduced the problem in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/arunk/5235528). (To run the gist, you will need to replace the mongodb server IP and database name in the user.js file and do a POST to the /register endpoint with `username` and `password` values.)

In it you will see the endpoints '/setval' and '/getval' which set values in the session and retrieves it, showing that session support is working. The endpoint '/authtest' gives an Unauthorized response, even after doing a POST to '/login'. The endpoint '/authdebug' gives more information - the error mentioned above.

Anyone have any ideas on what is going on? I'm running out of things to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `passport.authenticate` should only be used on routes which are actually used for authenticating the user; in your case, that would be the `/login` route.

For routes for which you want to make sure a user has previously authenticated, like `/authtest`, you need a middleware which checks if a user is authenticated:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/login'); // or your login page
}
// and
app.get('/authtest', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
 ...
});
```

An alternative for that middleware would be [connect-ensure-login](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login).